# Dynamically process .inc files with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML document that I wish to include as part of all files in a website:

Header XML Document (output referenced below as header.aspx):

```
<header>
<div class="welcome">Hello there!</div>
</header>
```

This is the part of a global XSL file executed on all pages which calls on the above:

Global XSL file

```
<xsl:template name="my-header">
<xsl:call-template name="my-output">
<xsl:with-param name="path">/inc/header.aspx</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

What I would like to do is be able to customize the output of the header.aspx based on where it is output. For example, if it outputs on a file listed in the directory /test1, it might output as:

```
<header>
<div class="welcome">Thank you for subscribing!</div>
</header>
```

But on a file in the directory /test2, it could be:

```
<h2 class="welcome">Sad to see you go!</div>
```

And whenever not specified, the default content would output.

Do I have any options for this? I realize I could create separate header includes and call upon them based on xsl:choose statements, but I'd rather have a single include file, since most of the content will remain the same across pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the URI of the header file as a parameter to the transformation, and load the file using the `document()` function with this URI as an argument.

A global stylesheet parameter is declared using a top-level `xsl:param` element (top-level means it's a child of `xsl:stylesheet`), and the way you supply a value depends on the processor API you are using to execute the stylesheet.